# I can't see what is triggering the invalid Syntax error

Tags: python, syntax-error

I am currently trying to replicate a packet sniffer in python that can parse udp, tcp, and ICPM packets.
As it is now no other compiler errors show except an invalid syntax error.

```
#packet sniffer for linux in python

import socket, sys
from struct import*

#A function that converts a string of 6 characters of ethernet address into dash seperated hex string
def ethernet_address (string):
    new_String = "%.2x:%.2x:%.2x:%.2x:%.2x:%.2x" % (ord(string(0)), ord(string(1)), ord(string(2)), ord(string(3)), ord(string(4)), ord(string(5)))
    return new_String

#Section that creates the socket
try:
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.ntohs(0x0003))
except socket.error as msg:
    print ("Socket could not be created, Error : ")
    print (msg)
    sys.exit()

#recieve a packet
while True:
    packet = sock.recvfrom(60000)

    #packet string from tuple
    packet = packet[0]

    #parse ethernet header
    ether_length = 14

    ether_Header = packet[:ether_length]
    ether = unpack('!6s6sh', ether_Header)
    ether_protocol = socket.ntohs(ether[2])
    print ("Destination MAC: " + ethernet_address(packet[0:6]) + "Source MAC: " + ethernet_address(packet[6:12]) + " Protocol: " + str(ether_protocol))

    #This section handles parsing IP packets
    if ether_protocol == 8:
        
        #Parse the IP header
        #take the first 20 character from the header
        ip_header = packet[ether_length:20 + ether_length]

        #now unpack
        iph = unpack('!BBHHHBBH4s4s', ip_header)

        version_ihl = iph[0]
        version = version_ihl >> 4
        ihl = version_ihl & 0xf

        iph_length = ihl * 4

        ttl = iph[5]
        protocol = iph[6]
        source_address = socket.inet_ntoa( iph[8] )
        destination_address = socket.inet_ntoa( iph[9] )

        print("Version: " + str(version) + " IP header length: " + str(ihl) + " TTL: " + str(ttl) + " Protocol: " + str(protocol + " Source Address: " + str(source_address) + " Destination Address: " + str(destination_address) )


        #This section handles parsing TCP packets
        if protocol == 6 : #This is the line with the error******************************************
            num = iph_length + ether_length
            tcp_header = packet[ num:num+20]

            #unpack
            tcph = unpack('!HHLLBBHHH', tcp_header)

            source_port = tcph[0]
            destination_port = tcph[1]
            sequence = tcph[2]
            acknowledgment = tcph[3]
            doff_reserve = tcph[4]
            tcph_length = doff_reserve >> 4

            print("Source Port: " + str(source_port) + " Destination Port: " + destination_port + " Sequence: " + sequence + " Acknowledgment: " + str(acknowledgment) + " TCP header length: " + str(tcph_length))

            h_size = ether_length + iph_length + tcph_length * 4
            data_size = len(packet) - h_size

            #get data
            data = packet[h_size:]

            print ("Data: "+ data)

        #This section Handles parsing ICMP packets
        elif protocol == 1:
            u = iph_length + ether_length
            icmph_length = 4
            icmp_header = packet[u:u+20]

            #unpack
            icmph = unpack('!BBH', icmp_header)

            icmp_type = icmph[0]
            code = icmph[1]
            checksum = icmph[2]

            print("Type: " + str(icmp_type) + " Code: " + str(code) + " Checksum: " + str(checksum))

            h_size = ether_length + iph_length + icmph_length
            data_size = len(packet) - h_size

            #retrive data
            data = packet[h_size]

            print("Data: " + data)

        #This section handles parsing UDP
        elif protocol == 17:
            u = iph_length +ether_length
            udph_length = 8
            udp_header = packet[u:u+8]

            #now unpack them
            udph = unpack('!HHHH', udp_header)

            src_port = udph[0]
            dest_port = udph[1]
            length = udph[2]
            checksum = udph[3]

            print("Source Port: " + str(src_port) + " Destination Port: " + str(dest_port) + " Length: " + str(length) + " Checksum: " + str(checksum) )

            h_size = ether_length + iph_length + udph_length
            data_size = len(packet) - h_size

            #get data
            data = packet[h_size]

            print("Data: " + data)

        else:
            print("Protocol is something other than UDP, ICMP, or TCP")

        print
```

The error is caused by the line:

```
if protocol == 6 :
```

Visual Studio says that this is a syntax error, but I'm of how because it is written just like every other if statement and they don't have a syntax error warning. What is the error if there is one?

Comment: Have you counted the number of opening and closing parentheses in the previous line?

Comment: Remember, when a statement is missing a parenthesis, it can't diagnose the error until it reads more lines.  That's why it points to the `if`.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are missing a bracket. `print("Version: " + str(version) + " IP header length: " + str(ihl) + " TTL: " + str(ttl) + " Protocol: " + str(protocol + " Source Address: " + str(source_address) + " Destination Address: " + str(destination_address) ))` should work.

Note: I added a bracket at the end but that might not be where it should be added for your code to function as intended despite removing the error. It seems `print("Version: " + str(version) + " IP header length: " + str(ihl) + " TTL: " + str(ttl) + " Protocol: " + str(protocol) + " Source Address: " + str(source_address) + " Destination Address: " + str(destination_address) )` is likely what you want.

Answer (score 1):

The error is found in the line above:

`print("Version: " + str(version) + " IP header length: " + str(ihl) + " TTL: " + str(ttl) + " Protocol: " + str(protocol + " Source Address: " + str(source_address) + " Destination Address: " + str(destination_address) )`

Specifically, the error comes from `... str(protocol + ...`, which should be `... str(protocol) + ...`.

Answer (score 0):

You have an unmatched parenthesis on the previous line:

```
print("Version: " + 
      str(version) + 
      " IP header length: " + 
      str(ihl) + 
      " TTL: " + 
      str(ttl) + 
      " Protocol: " + 
      str(protocol + 
          " Source Address: " + 
          str(source_address) + 
          " Destination Address: " + 
          str(destination_address)
         )
```

You probably want something like this:

```py
print("Version: " + 
      str(version) + 
      " IP header length: " + 
      str(ihl) + 
      " TTL: " + 
      str(ttl) + 
      " Protocol: " + 
      str(protocol) + 
      " Source Address: " + 
      str(source_address) + 
      " Destination Address: " + 
      str(destination_address) 
)
```

Also, consider using `" ".join(iterable)` to join `str`S with spaces. Concatenation is inefficient (not an issue here) and difficult to read (definitely an issue here).